# Include iOS Swift Projects Test Data in SonarQube Analysis

Tags: ios, swift, sonarqube

We are setting up a Swift iOS Project, build with fastlane, to be analysed by SonarQube with the SonarSwift Plugin.
Everything works so far except for information about the Tests.

We archived to add Code coverage by generating a report with slather (llvm-cov) and renaming it `Coverage.report` and filling `sonar.swift.coverage.reportPath` with the path.

We also generate *.junit files and feed them into `sonar.junit.reportsPath`. But those seem to never be included.
We tried only the path `./reports` and naming the files with `TEST-` prefix and `.xml` ending. We also tried a direct Path `./reports/TEST-report.xml`.

Did anybody got this to work? If yes, How? Is this even supported by SonarQube?

Comment: The property defined by SonarJava for coverage of Java projects is `sonar.junit.reportPaths` (You've got the 's' in the wrong place). But this is not going to work for Swift projects. [SonarSwift defines](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Swift+Coverage+Results+Import) `sonar.swift.coverage.reportPath`

Comment: The output of sonar-scanner said that `sonar.junit.reportPaths` is deprecated. Thats why we use `sonar.junit.reportsPath`.
Either way, that means that there is no way to add Unit Test data of Swift Projects to SonarQube?

Comment: can be that i am mixing those two up

Comment: In testing, I get the deprecation warning for `reportsPath`, not for `reportPaths`

Comment: But that still means that there is no way of adding junit style reports to a SonarQube Swift project?

Comment: That's what that means. Take a look at the [Generic Test Data](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Generic+Test+Data) format

Comment: @PeterSchumacher Did you end up finding a solution?

Comment: @Harsh In the End we wrote a converter from jUnit format to the Generic Test Data format

Answer (score 2):

According to https://community.sonarsource.com/t/number-of-unit-tests-is-zero/26104/6

JUnit reports only support Java.

For Swift, we need to convert the report to a generic type

Firstly, For **Coverage** (https://gist.github.com/lucascorrea/80f3d57a7f97b2365ef39839eefe68a1)

1. run test to generate test data
2. convert to coverage data with `xcrun llvm-cov show` that sonar can recognize
3. configure `sonar.swift.coverage.reportPath` to the report path generated by `xcrun`
4. you can run `sonar-scanner` to submit coverage data

```
    sh("xcodebuild -workspace ../brewdog.xcworkspace -scheme brewdog -sdk iphonesimulator -enableCodeCoverage YES -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 7,OS=11.3' GCC_GENERATE_TEST_COVERAGE_FILES=YES build test -derivedDataPath ../DerivedData")
    sh("xcrun llvm-cov show -instr-profile=$(find ../DerivedData -iname 'Coverage.profdata') ../DerivedData/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/brewdog.app/brewdog > ../DerivedData/Coverage.report")
```

Secondly, For **UnitTest** (https://github.com/azohra/forsis)
After you done this, you can check information like count of unit tests, success, fail, duration (There are some pictures in the above link)

This one is the same, you need to convert the test execution report to generic type with this tool

1. set up the convert
2. **[IMPORTANT]**configure `sonar.tests` AND `sonar.testExecutionReportPaths` in `sonar-project.properties`
3. run `sonar-scanner`

After done the two things
You can check the coverage AND unit test in the column in sonarqube website!!